# Display error in toast from imperative call

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, error-messages, toast, imperativeapex

I am trying to show the error message from the apex method exception as a toast message while doing imperative call in lwc. I am using ldsUtil.js to simplify the error message. But either way, I am not getting the error message in a toast.

```
        this.error = reduceErrors(error);
        console.log('error in save :'+error);
        console.log('reduceErrors(error) :'+this.error);
```

All above 3 lines are printing the error successfully but when I am trying pass reduceErrors(error) or this.error in toast message, the message is coming blank. See screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

```
    .catch(error =>{
        this.error = reduceErrors(error);
        console.log('error in save :'+error);
        console.log('reduceErrors(error) :'+this.error);
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Save status',
            message: this.error,
            //message: reduceErrors(error),
            variant: 'error',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
```

[image]

Imported Modules :

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { reduceErrors } from 'c/ldsUtils';
import saveStatus from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.saveStatus';
```

ldsUtils Link: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils

Comment: Can you share the modules you have for import?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Added modules

Comment: Can you also share reduceErrors function you have?

Comment: I have provided URL of the reduceErrors js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked. Tried with return value from reduceErrors inside JSON.stringify and it works like a charm even for the custom exceptions thrown using CalloutException.

Apex Custom Error:

```
    CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
    e.setMessage('Parameters are blank. Please contact your Administrator!');
    throw e;
```

LWC Js:

```
            this.showToastNotice('Product Setup',JSON.stringify(this.error),'error');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the below to see if this helps

```
const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Save status',
                message: error.body.message,
                variant: 'error'
            });
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Yes this works but this one is only for body.message . What about if error is present in error.message? For this reason only I am using reduce error function. Can you suggest workaround?

Comment: I am pretty sure that reduce function you have is causing issues. I suggest loop over error object and create a concatenation of all error messages and then use that in your code.